# ionic sqlite database data fetching synchronization error

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-sqlite-storage

I am new to Ionic framework. I have used Sqlite database in app. I need to fetch data from local database and send that to server.
Problem I am facing is, **my post method is getting executed before success callback is completed in $cordovaSQLite.execute method.** I need process to wait till it is completed.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$cordovaSQLite.execute($rootScope.db, query,[$scope.userId]).then(function(res) {
            // some process to make data in some format
            console.log('process is completed');
     }, function (err) {

          });
 console.log('after execute function');
```

This is rough form of my code. 
 I expect output as

```
process is completed.
after execute function.
```

But I am getting output as :

```
after execute function
process is completed.
```

Please help me to find solution for this. Thank you. !!!

Comment: can you say where you call your server api function ?

Comment: make server call here 'console.log('process is completed');'

Comment: @UttamKukadiya, Thank you for feedback. I have posted just sample of code, but for my actual scenario I have to fetch data from 5 different tables out of those 2 must be fetched simultaneously.So it is kind of hard for me to implement what you have suggested. Any other suggestions?

Comment: "2 must be fetched simultaneously" - can you fetch data using a single query i.e using join?